# Creating moving dot plot in MATLAB to video

Tags: matlab, plot, movie

I have 2 matrices

```
size(X)=size(y)=3600*140
```

They represent `140 nodes` position in `3600 secs`
I would like to create a movie of dots what will show them moving let say each `0.001sec` will show next all node position

i did:

```
for ii=1:3600
plot(x(ii,:),y(ii,:));
pause(0.0001);
end
```

Now it shows me the moving dots as wanted but

I would like each dot to have a colour
I would like to make a movie of those plots

Comment: Use `scatter` to colour the dots based on some criteria.

Comment: still looking for a way to make it a video

Comment: It's two questions I see from you today and both have solutions that can be easily found in the documentation. Maybe you could spend more time in searching by yourself before posting on stack overflow. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

here i got it to work. hope it will help someone else

```
writerObj = VideoWriter('runningNodes.avi');
open(writerObj);
plot(x(1,:),y(1,:));
axis tight
set(gca,'nextplot','replacechildren');
set(gcf,'Renderer','zbuffer');
for ii=1:3600
   plot(x(ii,:),y(ii,:));
   frame = getframe;
   writeVideo(writerObj,frame);
end

close(writerObj);
```